# React Native: can't connect to localhost even though it is accessible from the emulator browser

Tags: android, api, react-native, android-emulator

I am working on an android App , I have a weird issue , when I call my API I get this error :

[image]

[image]

Inside the emulator , when I open the browser and type the same URL configured inside my env file , I get the response !

But from the app , it doesn't work , I see nothing on the API terminal .

What I tried is  :

1)adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:300 => No result

2) using 10.0.2.2 => No result

3)I have also changed the port from 8081 to 1234 and added it to`(ctrl+m >> settings>>Debug server and host)` , close the app and launch it with `react-native run-android --port=1234`

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling any API, that is not able to invoke server. That is the issue. Trying checking Internet once as well.

Comment: The internet is good , when I open the browser on the emulator and call the same URL used on the app , it works

Comment: I have even restarted my machine but it is still the same :\

Comment: I have also changed the port from 8081 to 1234 and added it to```(ctrl+m >> settings>>Debug server and host)``` , and launch the app with ```react-native run-android --port=1234```